# Excel Formula: COUNTIFS() return value is wrong

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm using COUNTIFS() formula in Excel to count number of dates in a list,corresponding to a particular name. The output values are not accurate

Formula used:
**= COUNTIFS($G$31:$G$37,B32,$F$31:$F$37,"")**

COUNTIFS(range1 -text, comparison value, range2-date, check for value in range 2 )

The formula first compares a list range1 (G column) with a given text comparison, then it compares the range2 (F column) list to check for a date/blank space.

I've also tried this version of formula:

= COUNTIFS($G$31:$G$37,B32,$F$31:$F$37,"?????????")

and it returns a '0' every time

Am I using this function the right way?[Data Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6v4Ov.png)

Comment: Hi, you should add a screenshot to set an example, so the users can understand better what is the desired output.

Comment: If you asking if you are using `COUNTIFS()` correctly, then yes, but your data and criteria could be wrong. Searching for `???????` or empty cells as a value in U column.....? Is that really what you are after? You should indeed add sample data and expected output. Have a look at [ask] a question with a [mcve] and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: okay, attached a screenshot, with a simpler example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your provided sample data try:

```
=COUNTIFS($G$31:$G$37,B32,$F$31:$F$37,"<>")
```

In cel `C32` and drag down...

It was the `"<>"` (anything other then empty) you were looking for I assume.